# how to ellipsize label of y-axis with bar chart using achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine, android-graphview

I am very new to android Developer Especially for Graph. Now  I am creating a following graph using **AchartEngine** library but i have following problem:

**Q-1.** I want to Display label of left side with fixed width and remaining content with ellipsis.

**Q-2** When i am going to change orientation from portrait to landscape, graph is display like following second image. How to set Best Layout for graph.?

**Q-3** How to set 0 1 2 3...10 at X-axis?

I've written following code for this graph :

**createLayoutMethod():**

/** For Creating Graph Layout **/

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void createGraphLayout() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    /** Initialixation for Graph */
    /** objext of dataset which is put on Graph*/
    dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    series = new CategorySeries("Number of Customer");


    renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    //renderer.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 168, 240));

    mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    /** Setting for Renderer **/
    mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(13);
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {10,10,200,10});

    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setInScroll(true);

    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
    mRenderer.setScale(1);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);         // alignment of label x
    mRenderer.setXAxisMax(offer.length());
    mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);        // alignment of label y
    mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);         // color of label x
    mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);      // color of label y

    mRenderer.setLegendHeight(60);
    mRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

    mRenderer.setYAxisMax(offer.length());

    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

}
```

**putDataOnGraph():** for JSON DATA put on graph :

```
private void putDataOnGraph() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            for(int forOffer = 0; forOffer < offer.length(); forOffer++)
            {
                no_cust = 0;
                for(int forCust = 0; forCust < customer.length(); forCust++)
                {
                    if(offer.getJSONObject(forOffer).getInt("id") == customer.getJSONObject(forCust).getInt("offerId") && customer.getJSONObject(forCust).getInt("status") == 1)
                        no_cust = no_cust+1;
                }

                /** Check for x-axis maximum than customer **/
                maxX = no_cust > maxX ? no_cust : maxX;

                mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
                mRenderer.addXTextLabel(forOffer+1,offer.getJSONObject(forOffer).getString("offerTitle"));


                //Log.d("msg", ""+offer.getJSONObject(forOffer).getString("offerTitle") +" : "+no_cust);
                //Log.d("msg", ""+maxX);
                series.add(no_cust);
            }
            mRenderer.setYAxisMax(maxX);
            dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Image of Graph (Portrait):**
[image: Protrait Image with bar-chart]

**Image of Graph (Landscape):**
 [image: Landscape Image with bar-chart]

Your help would be appreciated.

**Thanks in advance....**

Comment: I suggest you write shorter questions instead of a big one with a lot of information.

Comment: Sorry @Dan But please give some solution if u have...

Comment: Hey @Dan I have used **achartengine** for android but it may not working in Android 4.0.1.
Is there any solution for that.?

Comment: I have solutions to punctual questions, not to huge ones.

Comment: AChartEngine does work with Android 4.x.

Comment: Please Answer me for first one from Above Questions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q1, you will have to compute the labels width in pixels and add only as much as it fits in your desired width. AChartEngine doesn't do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
/** For creating lable, display 10 char if length is > 10 **/

// getting String from JSON
lable = offer.getJSONObject(forOffer).getString("offerTitle");

//if string length is grater than 10 then display only first 10 char
if(lable.length() > 10)
{
    lable = lable.substring(0, 9);
}

mRenderer.addXTextLabel(forOffer+1,lable);
```

I have displayed fulltext in Toast when user Click on that

Comment: No Dan, Your Answer is Best. okay.

Comment: @Dan pratik butani is honest person he would like to make friend