# Horizontal bar chart using Achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I have created Horizontal bar chart successfully, but

in which i have 20 items but i want to display 5 items on y-axis and others are display when scroll down..

Is there any function or way to solve this.

I have asked question with image on this url : [how to ellipsize label of y-axis with bar chart using achartengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492702/how-to-ellipsize-label-of-y-axis-with-bar-chart-using-achartengine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the visibility of the items by restricting the visible area:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(minX);
renderer.setXAxisMax(maxX);
```

There are similar APIs for the Y axis.

Comment: Why onClick event of Bar chart is not working in when i put `mRenderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);`

Comment: Probably part of this issue: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=203

Comment: Yaa But also there is no solution